# Gmail label unread count

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

If you

- set up a filter

  ```
  Matches: from:(foo@gmail.com)
  Do this: Skip Inbox
  ```
- read a mail from that person
- apply label
- receive a reply

The label will not show a count for that reply or any other replys from that conversation, notice it says `Foo` instead of `Foo (1)`

> [image: label]

Comment: The count is the number of unread messages, your filter told Gmail to mark it as read.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep archiving is not the same as reading.

Comment: I add this as another case to what a I'm trying to [round-up solutions for](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74238/how-do-i-work-around-labels-being-applied-to-individual-messages-and-not-convers).

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56882/some-of-gmail-labels-show-the-of-unread-messages-and-some-dont)